# How do I use async programming in Perl?

Tags: performance, perl

Is there a simple way to do async in Perl?  I have the following logic for an Apache app:

```
get request
process request
write to log
return
```

what I want to do is to have the "write to log" part to be async, so that I can do the "return" part asap.

Comment: Why not use non-blocking calls to handle the write to log portion of your script?

Comment: What do you mean by "Apache app"? mod_perl? CGI? PSGI? standalone perl server with Apache as a front-end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, this typically entails the [POE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE) framework, but there is also a growing alternative (which I would want to try first) called [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent).

See [this question for learning materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948397/where-can-i-find-books-or-tutorials-for-perls-poe) for more information about learning POE. POE is a framework and it tends to eat your whole application. It also doesn't *look* like Perl, and sticks out. I believe it is a big learning curve for your typical application.

AnyEvent is simple continuation based asyncronous tasking, you should be able to figure it out fairly well with just the CPAN docs.

For your specific question you would use [AnyEvent's AIO](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent::AIO) or [POE's Read Write wheel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE::Wheel::ReadWrite)

Comment: thanks, was wondering if I missed anything obvious, but couldn't find any.  As this is part of an Apache app, neither solution seems attractive.  thanks tho

Comment: you could use a simple non-blocking socket to send the data to a POE log writing daemon. And, as daotoad said, so long as you're limiting one writing process per file then you can probably just use a non-blocking handle

Comment: AnyEvent is also faster and less intrusive than POE. From a former POE user himself, and now a happy AnyEvent user.

Answer (score 7):

Consider looking at [Coro](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Coro/).

From its CPAN documentation:

> Unlike the so-called "Perl threads" (which are not actually real threads but only the windows process emulation (see section of same name for more details) ported to unix, and as such act as processes), Coro provides a full shared address space, which makes communication between threads very easy. And Coro's threads are fast, too: disabling the Windows process emulation code in your perl and using Coro can easily result in a two to four times speed increase for your programs. A parallel matrix multiplication benchmark runs over 300 times faster on a single core than perl's pseudo-threads on a quad core using all four cores.

This includes `Coro::AIO`, a "truly asynchronous file and directory I/O", which might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need to write the logs before returning?

Assuming this is Apache mod_perl, it supports cleanup handlers that get triggered for the child process after the response is returned.

It seems what you REALLY want is for the logging not to stop the return, cleanup handlers would seem to do that without the need for async at all.

Comment: You're probably right, but it's a bad design right now, and it needs it to take advantage of the fact that it has some of the data right now, not just a simple logging.

Answer (score 4):

you can use threads in perl. 
create a thread that handle the logs.
this thread would have a buffer that the main thread can add messages to it

Answer (score 0):

Many-core Engine for Perl (MCE) comes with several examples demonstrating matrix multiplication in parallel across many cores. The readme contains benchmark results as well.

https://metacpan.org/source/MARIOROY/MCE-1.514/examples/matmult/README